# $A_6$ does not have a subgroup of order $120$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, simple-groups

I was reading the following proof of why there is no simple group of order $120$:

[A group of order $120$ cannot be simple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179324/a-group-of-order-120-cannot-be-simple)

And I couldn't understand the following: "so $A_6$ has a subgroup of order $120$ which is impossible".

Why is it impossible? Isn't the order of $A_6$ $6! / 2$, which equals $360$?

And since $120$ divides $360$, I can't see what's the problem in it...

Comment: It doesn't violate Lagrange. It violates the $n!$-theorem.

Comment: @the_fox Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will recite the theorem given in the linked question:

> Theorem: If a simple group $G$ has a proper subgroup $H$ such that $[G:H]=n$ then $G\hookrightarrow A_n$.

Now, Assume you have a subgroup $H \le A_6$, $|H|=120$. The group $A_6$ is simple and $[G:H] = 3$. Thus, by the theorem above, there is an embedding $A_6\hookrightarrow A_3$, a contradiction.

Comment: Ah, I can see it now. Is that the theorem that @the_fox referred as the "$n!$ theorem"?

Comment: The theorem in @the_fox 's post is a well known result that is often referred to as [Cayley's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem).  The corollaries he presented and the theorem above are based on the same idea (Cayley's theorem).

Comment: By your name I assume that you read hebrew. [This](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%98_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99) hebrew wikipedia page has some more information about the theorem and they present an important generalization which is roughly translated as "The refinement of Cayley's theorem" (I could not find a source in english, perhaps some one in here may know its name).

Comment: As simple as that.

Answer (score 3):

I am unable to find a proper reference for the theorem I am referring to, so here's the relevant part from page 4 of Isaacs' "Finite Group Theory" book.

[image]

Comment: Here let $G=A_6$ and $H$ be the subgroup of order $120$. $H$ has index $3$ in $G$ and therefore has three right cosets, including itself. $G$ acts faithfully on the cosets of $H$ by right multiplication - since there are $3$ cosets, the permutations of the cosets form a subgroup of $S_3$, which has order $6$. The kernel of this action is a non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$ of index $3$ or $6$ (we know the action is transitive on cosets, hence the factor $3$ is known). But $G$ is simple, and this is a contradiction.